# Possible to make a Quiz with HTML/CSS only?

Tags: html, css

I am currently studying math and thought of an idea, depending on if it is possible.
I want to add in let say 100 math equations, but only one question should be displayed at once until you type in the correct answer and click next.

Is this possible with HTML only or would I need other languages?
I will be running it locally so hiding answers in source code is not important.

Comment: No, it's not possible, You will need to use a scripting language like Javascript.

Comment: I can think of an extremely hacky, overly complicated approach that *might* work using CSS … but it's stupid, and bloated, and hard. If you want logic, use a programming language. Preferably a server side one.

Comment: Thanks guys, thats all I needed to know.

Comment: You could use HTML5 LocalStorage to fit in all the data, but that is only being saved to the user's browser, so it is completely private in that matter.  But you will need JavaScript to handle saving data. There are some guides around the interwebs on creating a LocalStorage powered guiz, so I recommend Googling it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible using HTML only as far as I know. Ideally you need a database where you store your questions, your users, their previous answers, the correctness of the answers and their overall performance. You would need to create a register/login screen using a server-side language. On the server you would need two core functionalities closely related to the question feature. The first is to randomize a question which was not asked yet, the other is to handle the answer of the user. A user would load the page, the question randomizer would run on the server and whenever the user answers a question, your client-side should send a POST request to the server with the answer to the question and handle the response of the server (display the next randomized question).

However, you might want a very quick solution before you implement the database. In that case you could store the questions in a Javascript array, on page load randomize the question, display it to the user and when the user answers the question, store the answer, display whether it was correct, add the question to another array storing answered questions and remove the item from the question array, then randomize again and display again. This is not an ideal solution, but can be a temporary quick solution to have some success before you start the longer solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a basic approach, you can go with this:

```js
var questions = [];
var loadedQuestions = [];
var questionPosition = 0;
var score = 0;

var question = {
  "title": "This is the title",
  "answers": [{
    "title": "This is not Correct",
    "correct": 0
  }, {
    "title": "This is correct",
    "correct": 1
  }, {
    "title": "This is not",
    "correct": 0
  }, {
    "title": "This either",
    "correct": 0
  }]

}
questions.push(question);
var question = {
  "title": "This is the second question",
  "answers": [{
    "title": "This is not Correct",
    "correct": 0
  }, {
    "title": "This is correct",
    "correct": 1
  }, {
    "title": "This is not",
    "correct": 0
  }, {
    "title": "This either",
    "correct": 0
  }]

}
questions.push(question);

var question = {
  "title": "This is the third",
  "answers": [{
    "title": "This is not Correct",
    "correct": 0
  }, {
    "title": "This is correct",
    "correct": 1
  }, {
    "title": "This is not",
    "correct": 0
  }, {
    "title": "This either",
    "correct": 0
  }]

}
questions.push(question);

function updateScore(result) {
  if(result){
    score++;
  }else{
    score--;
  }
  $("#score").text(score);
}

function answering() {
  var correct = $(this).data("correct");
  $(this).addClass(correct ? "correct" : "wrong");

  updateScore(correct);
}

function loadQuestions() {
  $.each(questions, function() {
    var question = $("<div></div>");
    question.addClass("question");

    var title = $("<h2></h2>");
    title.addClass("title");
    title.text(this.title);

    var answers = $("<ul></ul>");
    answers.addClass("answers");

    $.each(this.answers, function() {
      answer = $("<li data-correct='" + this.correct + "'></li>");
      answer.addClass("answer");
      answer.text(this.title);
      answers.append(answer);
    });

    question.append(title);
    question.append(answers);

    loadedQuestions.push(question);
  });
}

function displayQuestion() {
  $("#questions").empty();
  $("#questions").append(loadedQuestions[questionPosition]);
  $("li.answer").click(answering);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadQuestions();
  displayQuestion();

  $("#next").click(function() {
    if (questionPosition < (loadedQuestions.length - 1)) {
      questionPosition++;
      displayQuestion();
    }
  });

  $("#prev").click(function() {
    if (questionPosition > 0) {
      questionPosition--;
      displayQuestion();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.correct {
  background-color: #61e02b;
  color: #FFF;
}

.wrong {
  background-color: #e34d45;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
The ultimate quiz
</h1>
<p>
  This is a test. Please, click on the "next" o "prev" button to move across questions.
</p>
<div id="questions">

</div>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>

<p>
  Your score is:
  <spam id="score">0</spam>
</p>
```

Comment: @Jon I update the answer

Comment: Thanks you very much, this was really cool! How hard would it be to have one answer only and a input text area to write the answer instead of radrio buttons? I tryed changing the <UL> tags to <Input> but it wouldnt recognize any answer as right or wrong. Anyways, apreciate you did this, thanks you!

Comment: It shouldn't be much more complicated, but it need's a bit more than changing the HTML. You need to write the JS logic to check if the given answer matches the correct one, that should be stored somewhere, like a `data` attribute.